# Search NSArray of NSDictionary using NSPredicate

Tags: ios, objective-c

All, I am trying to do the following and getting no result and not sure where I am going wrong. In my case `srchString` will be passed from the searchDisplayController so the search string will be dynamic. Just for the heck of it tried hardcoding the value as in the example below and it nothing returned. So looking for some help on how to address this one. Thanks

```
 (
 {
        amount = "-243.77";
        date = "May 21, 2014";
        description = "Preauthorized Debit";
        extraMap =             {
            MEMO = "ATT              Payment";
            RUNBAL = "$100,159.51";
            id = 123456789454444440000002
        };
        longDate = "2014-05-22";
        referenceId = " ";
        sortDate = "2014-05-22 04:00:00 +0000";
        transactionDateAsCal = "1432267200000:America-New_York";
    },
    {
        amount = "5058.74";
        date = "May 21, 2014";
        description = "Deposit";
        extraMap =             {
            MEMO = "WXYZAWQH          BATCH";
            RUNBAL = "$100,159.51";
            id = 124259821201505220000001;
        };
        longDate = "2014-05-22";
        referenceId = " ";
        sortDate = "2014-05-22 04:00:00 +0000";
        transactionDateAsCal = "1432267200000:America-New_York";
    }
)

NSArray *listOfKeys = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"amount", @"date", @"description", @"memo", @"runbal", @"referenceId",@"longDate", @"id", nil];

//Sample test. This search string will be passed from the searchDisplayController.
NSString *srchString = @"Preauthorized";

//If the searchstring has an exact match then it works Like below
//NSString *srchString = @"Preauthorized Debit";

NSMutableArray *subpredicates = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSString *key in listOfKeys) {
    NSPredicate *subpredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K contains[cd] %@", key, srchString];
    [subpredicates addObject:subpredicate];
}

NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:subpredicates];
NSLog(@"predicate %@",resultPredicate);

NSArray *tempArr = [transactionList filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
NSLog(@"tempArr %@", tempArr);
```

Comment: Your filtering transactionList but that's not called anywhere in your code. Probably why it's not returning anything. Additionally your calling a predicate that's inside a loop

Comment: transactionList is basically the sample NSArray that I listed above. Probably should have specified that..sorry about that.

Comment: Your sub predicate can't be reached by ResultPredicate because it's in a loop.

Comment: subpredicate is getting added to the MutableArray subpredicates and that is what is being used to setup the NSPredicate

Comment: I read it wrong because of the 's' at the end. Not good choice to name something so similar. Even for yourself. If you come back to it in a year that might throw you off. Regardless show transactionList if you don't mind. Since that's what your filtering ultimately

Comment: Additionally for your testing array (listOfKeys) subpredicate `NSPredicate` should be using `self` because %K is a var substitution for key path (something arrays don't have)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay since your not really active with the comments I'll post an answer. Normally I don't like to do this unless I'm sure what the OP is asking for, in this case, I'm assuming I'm confident I understand your vision. First lets talk about what's going on with your example....and lets take away the 'hard coded' portion you shared, I think that will just confuse future question seekers due to grammatical errors and complications.

**First** thing, your using `%K` for one predicate, `%K` is a var arg substitution for a key path. In your instance, you stated you have an **array** of dictionaries, which ultimately means it's an array, which is not KVO compliant, ergo, will not work.

**Secondly**, you don't need a loop at all, in fact, I wouldn't encourage it for your circumstance. It can easily be filtered down solely with one predicate.

So lets sum this up for you, and for future question seekers :

Lets say we have an `NSArray` of `NSDictionary` as stated above. For example we'll use the data the OP provided above:

```
NSArray *firstTransactionKeys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"amount",@"date",@"description",@"longdate", nil];
NSArray *firstTransactionValues = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"-243.77",@"May 21, 2014",@"Preauthorized Debit",@"2014-05-22 04:00:00", nil];
NSArray *secondTransactionKeys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"amount",@"date",@"description",@"longdate", nil];
NSArray *secondTransactionValues = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"5058.74",@"May 21, 2014",@"Deposit",@"2014-05-22 04:00:00", nil];

NSArray *transactionList = [NSArray new];
transactionList = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:firstTransactionValues forKeys:firstTransactionKeys], [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:secondTransactionValues forKeys:secondTransactionKeys], nil]; 
NSLog(@"Original Transactions: %@", transactionList);

(
    {
        amount = "-243.77";
        date = "May 21, 2014";
        description = "Preauthorized Debit";
        longdate = "2014-05-22 04:00:00";
    },
        {
        amount = "5058.74";
        date = "May 21, 2014";
        description = Deposit;
        longdate = "2014-05-22 04:00:00";
    }
)
```

Now that we have the data we want, all we need to do is with code-friendly format, filter the array down to a keyword or search term:

```
///////Example purposes only. User types in 'Preauthorized Debit'////////
NSString *searchWord = @"Preauthorized Debit";
```

Now just use an `NSPredicate` with %@ (var arg for object value).

```
NSPredicate *searchPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@", searchWord];
```

Create your new array from the predicate:

```
NSArray *tempArr = [transactionList filteredArrayUsingPredicate:searchPredicate];
NSLog(@"tempArray = %@", tempArr);
```

And that's it, hopefully that helps you somewhat grasp things